# Format output for ls

Tags: ls

I'm looking for a way to list the content in a folder with output in this format:

```
folder/file.txt
```

Similar to the output for the git command:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' folder/*` ?

Comment: Maybe `find . -type f` or `find . -type f | sed 's#^\./##'` or `find . -type f | cut -c3-`?

Comment: Thanks @Bodo
This is close:
find . -type f | sed 's#^\./##'


But I also get all files/folders that starts with . (dots)
Can I get rid of those?

Comment: @ELU Please [edit] your question and add an example to show which files/folders you have including those you don't want to see and how you want the output to look like. `find . -mindepth 1 -iname '.*' -prune -o -type f -print | cut -c3-` There might be a simpler way depending on your preconditions.

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit unclear but your last command did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Instead of `-print | cut -c3-`  you can use `-printf '%P\n'`

Comment: And like this you can run the same with `-maxdepth`:  `find . -maxdepth 1 -path '*/.*' -prune -o -type f -printf '%P\n'`

Comment: @ELU Anyway you should make your question more clear as I already suggested. The purpose of this site is not only to answer the question for you personally, but also as a reference for others that may have similar questions. With example data we can test our proposed solutions and write an answer based on the proposals from the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git ls-tree -r --name-only` seems to list all files recursively including hidden ones but excluding files of type *directory*, sorted by name using `strcmp()` as the sort comparison function.

So to get something approaching to list the contents of a directory as opposed to the list of files at a revision of a `git` repository, in `zsh` you could do:

```
LC_ALL=C print -orC1 -- **/*(NDoN^-/)
```

That is:

- `LC_ALL=C` set only for `print` for its `-o` to sort by byte value (instead of locale collation order)
- `print -orC1`: `print`, `o`rdered, `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn.
- `**/*`: recursive globbing
- `(NDoN^-/)` sort qualifier, including `N`ullglob (to expand to nothing when there's no file), `D`otglob (to include hidden files), `oN` for `N`ot `o`rdered as `print` will order them any way. `^-/` excludes files of type *directory* (determined after symlink resolution).

With GNU tools, you can get something equivalent with:

```
find . ! -xtype d -printf '%P\0' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -z |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

- `! -xtype d`: exclude directories and symlinks to directories.
- `-printf '%P\0'` print the path *within* `.` (that is without the `./` prefix) NUL-delimited.
- `LC_ALL=C sort -z` sort that list by byte value instead of locale collation order.
- `tr '\0' '\n'`: translate the NULs to newlines for the list to be legible to a human user (though we no longer know where each file name (which could be made of several lines) starts and stops).

To exclude hidden files, change to:

```
LC_ALL=C print -orC1 -- **/*(NoN^-/)
```

If you don't mind getting the collation order (like `ls` or `sort`, but not `git ls-tree` do by default) instead of `strcmp()` order, you can  simplify it do:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(N^-/)
```

(as that's the default order for globs).

Or with GNU `tools`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -prune -o ! -xtype d -printf '%P\0' |
  sort -z |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

`LC_ALL=C` is needed for `find` for its `.?*` to match *all* hidden files even those that contain byte values not forming valid characters in your locale.

`git ls-tree` however encodes filenames containing non-ascii characters (subject to the `core.quotePath` config setting which can be set of a per-repository basis, `true` by default) or control characters or `\` or `"` as C-style strings (such as `"foo\"bar\nbaz"`). To do something similar, you could use GNU `ls --quoting-style=c-maybe` in the `C` locale:

`zsh` with GNU `ls`:

```
print -rNC1 -- **/*(N^-/) |
  LC_ALL=C xargs -r0 ls --quoting-style=c-maybe -1dU --
```

GNU tools:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -prune -o ! -xtype d -printf '%P\0' |
  sort -z |
  LC_ALL=C xargs -r0 ls --quoting-style=c-maybe -1dU --
```

Note that `ls` outputs a file called `\` as `\` while `git ls-tree` outputs it as `"\\"`. If you really cared, you could always pipe the whole thing to `sed -e '/^"/b' -e '/\\/!b' -e 's/\\/&&/g' -e 's/.*/"&"/'` to get the same output.

`zsh` can give you a different style of quoting if you use the `:q` modifier in it's glob qualifier. One example with a `git` repository with weird file names:

```
$ ls -AFq
''$'\351'  ''$'\n'  '"'  '\'   a  'a'$'\n''b'   B      é      .git/  'my dir'/
''$'\b'    ' '      "'"  '~'   A   b            dir/   .foo   link@
```

```
$ git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD
"\b"
"\n"

"\""
'
.foo
A
B
"\\"
a
"a\nb"
b
link
my dir/file
~
"\303\251"
"\351"
```

```
$ print -rC1 -- **/*(N^-/:q)
\ 
\"
\'
\\
\~
$'\351'
$'\b'
$'\n'
a
A
a$'\n'b
b
B
é
link
my\ dir/file
```

```
$ LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -prune -o ! -xtype d -printf '%P\0' |
pipe>   sort -z |
pipe pipe>   LC_ALL=C xargs -r0 ls --quoting-style=c-maybe -1dU --
"\351"
"\b"
"\n"

"\""
'
\
~
a
A
"a\nb"
b
B
"\303\251"
link
my dir/file
```

(note the missing `.foo` (though it is in the repository and listed by `git ls-tree`), `.git` (not in the repository as that's just where `git` stores metadata), the differences in encoding of the `\` file and the differences of sort order (especially regarding lower vs upper case, YMMV in your own locale)).